# Laravel passport API fails to authenticate

Tags: linux, laravel, api, jwt, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel application that I built on Windows. It is an api by passport and frontend by Vuejs and on windows and works perfect. But the problem is now that it is in a Linux server when I am authenticating always returns "Unauthorized error" even though the password and user name is correct!

In the constructor I tried:

`$this->middleware('auth:api');`
And this on the routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function()
{ 
   //Routes here
}
```

with no difference!.

But when I login I get the tokens. But does not work! when I try the token provided!.

The headers that i send is as the image shows [image: using POstman]

The problem on windows works and linux does not!

Comment: Hi, when you try login with Postman like this does it work? Maybe problem is with http headers? - Please try add Content-Type : application/json

Comment: Yes the login works!. But other controllers that need authorization does not work. They all return 401 error.

Comment: Could you please provide your controller code?

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Budget_templates;
use App\Http\Resources\Budget_templatesResource;
class Budget_templatesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $Budget_templates = new Budget_templates;
        if ($Budget_templates->count()) {
             $Budget_templates=$Budget_templates->all();
            return response($Budget_templates, $status = 200);
        }else{
            return response($content = '', $status = 204);
        }
       
    }

Comment: One more thing:  Have you changed in config/auth.php api driver to passport?

Comment: Yes i have Milena Schmidt and on windows works perfectly well!